# How to add a field to the existing fields inside a subscription notification under content in Tool bar?

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

I'm editing a body of subscription notification and has some fields in the body that are not in the toolbar section. So, how can I add a field to the toolbar where I can add that into the body of subs.noti?

I have tried application wise as well as questionnaire, but nothing comes to my mind

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields that are missing from the toolbar's **Select a field** drop-down have a status of Active?

Comment: They are active

Comment: Then they should show up in the dropdown.  If not, you can manually add the field to the Body by entering [Field:My Field Name].